# Two candidates in method Enumerable.Where

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone encountered this problem? I have two same candidates to method Enumerable.Where
And what is the Func'2 and Func'3?

When i trying to filter enumerable

```
var subItems = itemsToShow.Where(item => item.Visible);
```

I have an error:

Cannot resolve method 'Where(lambda expression)', candidates are

```
System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Func'2) (in calss Enumerable)
System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<T>, System.Func'3) (in calss Enumerable)
```

On .Net 3.5 this work perfect

Comment: For people, who come here for a solution to this error message, not related to this example: 

You will get the same error if you forget to use two equal signs - and just use one.
So 

var what = db.Items.Where(x => x.Id = 123);

Will give the same error.

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) tells you that there are in fact two overloads.

One just filters based on a predicate, and the second overload also takes the index of the item in the enumeration into account.

Comment: My code work on .Net 3.5 and don't work after changing framework version to 4

Answer (score 0):

`Func'3` and `Func'2` meens that  it is a generic class with 2 and 3 type parameters.

I assume that first is for `Func<T, bool>` where `T` is your earlier defined type.
and `Func<T, int, bool>` the same plus indexer.

`Func<T, int, bool>` - it is a predicate that accepts two arguments of types `T` and `int` and returns `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the solution and see the detailed error. Mine was a nullable boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because I was trying to use `.Contains` on a `List` type, while what I needed was `.Any`

for example

```
var myObjectsList = new List<MyClass>();

// instead of this
myObjectList.Contains(x => x.Id == 1)
// use this
myObjectList.Any(x => x.Id == 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try casting to an IQueryable.  Like so: itemsToShow.AsQueryable()